# Geodesics on Lorentzian (2n-1)-Spheres

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

I know that if we endow $S^{n}$ with the round Riemannian metric, we will be able to join the North pole and the South pole by an unlimited number of geodesics, in particular the meridians, and indeed this is intuitive if  we think about $S^2$. Yet I was now wondering how it would work for a Lorentzian metric in $S^3$, would we still have a similiar situation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to have a manifold with the topology of $S^3$ and a Lorentzian metric. The corresponding maximally-symmetric Lorentzian spaces of constant (non-zero) curvature would be [deSitter space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Sitter_space) (dS) and [Anti-deSitter space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-de_Sitter_space) (AdS). These would be the closest analogs to spheres.

Comment: found this https://books.google.com/books?id=QUuLp4W1bFAC&pg=PA531&lpg=PA531&dq=lorentz+metric+on+S^3&source=bl&ots=kIIzvlcjUu&sig=ec78ZKTojCYi590zyX1VAEQqKd8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5mgXVdPkDtHXoATYuoGoBw&ved=0CDoQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=lorentz%20metric%20on%20S^3&f=false

Comment: S^3 is parallelizable, so you can extract a Lorentz metric on the sphere from that: in particular denote the three parallelizing vector fields by $\partial T,\partial X, \partial Y$, use your favorite Riemannian metric to extract one forms $dT, dX, dY$ and set a Lorentz metric (using (-,+,+) conventions) $g =-  dT \otimes dT + dX \otimes dX + dY \otimes dY$.

Comment: To a certain extent, I might expect confusion to arise from the fact that we often are expecting a 4-manifold when we talk about Lorentz metrics, and this is a 3-manifold.

Comment: I believe there is a theorem that states that you can always endow an odd-dimensional sphere with a Lorentzian metric. I was just trying to understand how geodesics would behave in that case, in particular if we would still find several geodesics connecting two points.